# When is a group isomorphic to the infinite cyclic group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

I am learning algebra and I am a bit confused.

Let's say I have a finitely presented group $G$, can anyone tell me if it is possible to find out if $G\cong \mathbb{Z}$?

Thanks

Comment: In general determining whether a finite presentation defines the trivial group is an undecidable problem. This is surely equally as hard.

Comment: Without specifying some properties of the group, problems like these tend to be unsolvable.  See [The Word Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups)

Comment: If G is infinite, and If all of $G$ can be generated by one element, then it is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$

Comment: Others have pointed out that this problem is undecidable, but it is semi-decidable in the sense that if $G \cong \mathbb{Z}$ then it is possible to prove it.

Comment: While this is undecidable, do not despair.  It is worthwhile to practice equivalence transformations on presentations, since many *bounded* (bounded in the number of equivalence steps) versions of this problem are decidable.  Also, practicing finding and proving the isomorphism is a very good thing to do.  This is similar to developing an intuition for recognizing (probably or nearly) equivalent expressions in elementary algebra -- a skill that comes from practice and manipulating such expressions.

Comment: Note that the answers assume that by "I have a finitely presented group $G$" you mean "I have a given finite presentation".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No. More strikingly: it is undecidable if a finitely presented group is the trivial group! These facts were proven (independently) by Adyan and Rabin in the 50s. The key idea is that of "Markov properties":

> A property $\mathcal{P}$ of finitely presentable groups is a *Markov property* if:
>
> 1. the property $\mathcal{P}$ is preserved under group isomorphism.
> 2. there exists a finitely presentable group (a witness) $K_+$ with property $\mathcal{P}$.
> 3. there exists a finitely presentable group $K_{-}$ which cannot be embedded as a subgroup in any finitely presentable group with property $\mathcal{P}$.

The theorem is as follows:

> **Theorem** (Adyan-Rabin). If $\mathcal{P}$ is a Markov property then there does not exist an algorithm with input a finite presentation $G = \langle \mathbf{x} \mid \mathbf{r}\rangle$ and which decides whether or not the group $G$ defined by this presentation has property $\mathcal{P}$.

For a reference, see Lydon and Schupp, *Combinatorial group theory*, Section IV.4, p192. I tried to set this theorem, and some related results, in the "big picture" of group theory in [this old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/479311/10513).

So, for the examples I mentioned above:

- being infinite cyclic is a Markov property: it is preserved under isomorphism, and take $K_+=\langle a\mid-\rangle$ and $K_-=\langle a\mid a^2\rangle$.
- being trivial is a Markov property: it is preserved under isomorphism, and take $K_+=\langle a\mid a\rangle$ and $K_-=\langle a\mid a^2\rangle$.

Another example:

- being finite is a Markov property: it is preserved under isomorphism, and take $K_+=\langle a\mid a\rangle$ and $K_-=\langle a\mid -\rangle$.

Now, being infinite is *not* a Markov property (as every finite group embeds in an infinite group). However, this is still undecidable as it is the complement of a Markov property: Suppose I have an algorithm with input $\langle \mathbf{x}\mid\mathbf{r}\rangle$ and which tells me if the associated group is infinite. If it returns "no" then my group is finite. Hence, I can detect finiteness, a contradiction.

A third example (hyperbolic groups are standard objects in geometric group theory):

- being hyperbolic is a Markov property: it is preserved under isomorphism, and take $K_+=\langle a\mid a\rangle$ and $K_-=\langle a, b\mid [a, b]\rangle$. (It is a theorem that $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ does not embed into any hyperbolic group.)

---

Derek Holt points out in the comments to the question that the problem is semi-decidable. I thought it would be a good idea to build on this a litte:

> **Lemma.** *If* $G=\langle \mathbf{x}\mid\mathbf{r}\rangle$ is (infinite) cyclic *then* it is possible to prove it.

This does not contradict undecidability, as you will never know when to conclude that the input group $G$ is *not* infinite cyclic. That is, suppose that we input $\langle \mathbf{x}\mid\mathbf{r}\rangle$ into the procedure given by the above lemma, and it doesn't terminate after 1 hour. What can we conclude? Well, we can conclude *nothing*! It may be the case that the underlying group *is* infinite cyclic, but we need 100 years of computation to prove that it is so.

*Proof of Lemma.*
Write $\mathbf{x}=\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$. If $G$ is cyclic then there exists a word $w\in F(\mathbf{x})$ and integers $p_0, \ldots, p_n$ such that $x_i=_Gw^{p_i}$. So, enumerate all consequences of the relators and then check each consequence to see if it has the form $x_i^{-1}w^{p_i}$ for some $i, p_i, w$. Terminate the procedure if we have a "complete" set $\{x_i^{-1}w^{p_i}\mid i=1, \ldots, n\}$ with $w$ fixed. If we conclude that $G$ is cyclic then we can easily determine if it is infinite cyclic, as required.

Sticking with the examples above, we also have the following lemma:

> **Lemma.** *If* $G=\langle \mathbf{x}\mid\mathbf{r}\rangle$ is trivial *then* it is possible to prove it.

*Proof.*
Write $\mathbf{x}=\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$. Enumerate all consequences of the relators and then check each consequence to see if it has the form $x_i$. Terminate the procedure if we have a "complete" set $\{x_i^{-1}\mid i=1, \ldots, n\}$.

Comment: For reference for the OP, there are smaller categories of groups (e.g., word-hyperbolic groups) in which the word problem and similar problems are decidable.

Comment: The analogy to Rice's theorem is interesting and possibly instructive. (Or, viewed another way, this _is_ Rice's theorem. I think.)

Comment: This is the clearest summary of this stuff that I’ve ever seen.

Comment: The statement of the Adian–Rabin theorem reminds me of Rice's theorem.

Comment: In the proof of the first lemma, I don't think that if $\langle\mathbf x|\mathbf r\rangle$ is cyclic then there is one among the $x$'s such that all the others are powers of that one. For example, $(\mathbb Z,+)$ is generated by $2$ and $3$. So the search in the proof should terminate when you find some word $w$ such that all the $x$'s have been found to be powers of $w$ (whether or not $w$ is one of the given generators).

Comment: @Andreas Yes, of course. Thanks for pointing this out. I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.  If there's only one generator, the answer is easy.  But if there is more than one generator, then in general no, the problem is provably undecidable!