# Proving for a group using relations

Tags: group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

> Let $$G = \langle a,b: ab^2 = b^3, ba^3 = a^2b\rangle.$$ Show that
>
> 1. $a^2b^4a^{-2}= b^9$
> 2. $a^3b^4a^{-3}= b^9$ (Hint: Use $ba^3 = a^2b$ and 1.)
> 3. $|G| = 1$. (Hint: Use 1 and 2.)

I have successfully shown 1 but I am currently struggling on how to show 2 using the provided hints and don't know how to approach 3. I would appreciate any help in furthering my understanding of this.

Edit: My solution for 1.

> $a^2b^4a^{-2} = aab^2b^2a^{-2} = a(ab^2)b^2a^{-2} = ab^3ab^2a^{-2} = ab^3(ab^2)a^{-2} = ab^3b^3aa^{-2} = ab^6a^{-1} = ab^2b^4a^{-1} = b^3ab^4a^{-1} = b^3(ab^2)b^2a^{-1} = b^3b^3ab^2a^{-1} = b^6(ab^2)a^{-1} = b^6b^3aa^{-1}=b^9$

Comment: Please provide more context. For example, share your solution 1.

Comment: Compare with [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3500354/showing-langle-a-b-mid-ab2%EF%BC%9Db3a-ba2%EF%BC%9Da3-rangle-is-isomorphic-to-the-trivia), interchanging $a$ and $b$. No need to compute $b^9$.

Comment: That is no duplicate, @DietrichBurde. This problem concludes that $G$ is trivial, whereas that answer *uses* that $G$ is trivial.

Comment: @shaun No, it doesn't. It shows: *One way to see that $\langle a,b\mid ab^2＝b^3a, ba^2＝a^3\rangle$ defines the trivial group is to use the second relator as follows:* So it is shown that the group is trivial.

Comment: My mistake: I didn't read it properly, I guess, @DietrichBurde. Sorry!

Comment: Alright, then let me close it, before the OP tries to work with this unnecessarily complicated computation.

Comment: @DietrichBurde but the question specifically wants me to compute for $b^9$ and then use the fact that since those elements equal $b^9$ to show that the group is trivial

Comment: Don't just go by what the questions wants. The question can be solved much better, so why to follow this. Your teacher will be delighted when you come up with a better solution.